# How to export to CSV file from PostgreSQL using BufferedWriter in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am preparing a batch of SQL PreparedStatement in the following format to export data to CSV files.

```
COPY (SELECT ..... FROM ..... LIMIT 500 OFFSET ...) TO STDOUT (format 'csv', delimiter ',') '|'
```

Now I want to hook BufferedWriter to the above SQL statement so that output goes to the specified file. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Have you done any research yourself?

Comment: I have recently started coding on Java and my knowledge is limited. Regarding the research - I have searched in Google and came across following link - http://zetcode.com/java/postgresql/. In this CopyManager is used. I was suggested to use BufferedWrite. Any small hint would help.

Comment: Ok, I think you should use either the COPY function you have in your example or java as in the link but not both.

Comment: Used CopyManager and it worked. The issue was due to the Connection, which was HikariProxyConnection. Casting to BaseConnection was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you really need this construction. In fact, you have two goals to achive: read data from database, and write it to file.

Example of using JDBC in PostgreSQL is here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html

Example of writing data to file: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html

Just combine them together.